# avoid transition after hover js

Tags: javascript, onclick, hover

Hello i have this code:

```
function goto(id, t){   
    //animate to the div id.
    $(".contentbox-wrapper").animate({"left": -($(id).position().left)}, 500);

    // remove "active" class from all links inside #nav
    $('#nav a').removeClass('active');

    // add active class to the current link
    $(t).addClass('active');

}
```

this code active the horizontal-scroll of the slideshow, and inside the single page of slideshow are presents more div (div1 , div2 , div3) and at each of div is attached this code:

```
$("#div1").hover(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.css({'z-index' : '10', 'boxShadow' : '1px 3px 6px #444', 'position': 'fixed' }).animate({
       'height': "390",
       'width' : "840",
       'marginTop' : "-12",
       'marginLeft' : "-12",
    });
},
function() {
   var $this = $(this);
   $this.css({'z-index' : '1', 'boxShadow' : '0px 0px 0px ', 'position': 'static' }).animate({
       'height': "350",
       'width' : "800",
       'marginTop' : "0",
       'marginLeft' : "0"
    });
});
```

this is the code in HTML:

```
<a href="#" onClick="goto('#about', this); return false; " >
<div id="div2" style="background-color:#fff; width:250px;border:1px solid #000;min-height:250px; color:black;">
                                    ABOUT
                                 </div></a>
```

the problem is that when I click on a div that is present in the page One of slideshow, for example div1, and I need it to move horizontally on the second page,having   the mouse inside the div latter moves with the scroll and don't stay in the page One, how can I avoid this?

I wish that when I click the system goes to the second page of the slideshow, but not with him also drag the div I clicked to move to the second page.

Comment: Can you setup an example on jsfiddle?

Comment: see this http://jsfiddle.net/6qtw7/ but in this example the slideshow dont go.

Comment: this is the slideshow that i use: http://gazpo.com/2012/03/horizontal-content-scroll/

Comment: You don't want the transition which causes the div to come up? or you don't want the animation?

Comment: I wish that by clicking on the slideshow scroll div1 on second page without which remain active on mouseover.

Comment: Ok this is the correctly example: http://jsfiddle.net/S8Nqm/ if you click the div2 is transported on Work Page. I do not want to be transported to the Work page or any other page, i want you once you have clicked on the div ClickHere return to "basic version" page and scroll to the second page.

Comment: I've added an answer please have a look

Answer (score 0):

Changed the following code, inside the `goto()`. Here I am check if `#div2` is in the *hovered* state.

If yes, then I take it back to it's original state AND ONLY THEN I move to the next page.

```
if (parseInt($("#div2").css("z-index"), 10) > 1) {
    $("#div2").css({
        'z-index': '1',
        'boxShadow': '0px 0px 0px ',
        'position': 'static'
    }).animate({
        'height': "250",
        'width': "250",
        'marginTop': "0",
        'marginLeft': "0"
    }, function(){
        $(".contentbox-wrapper").animate({
        "left": -($(id).position().left)
       }, 600);
   });
}
else {
    $(".contentbox-wrapper").animate({
        "left": -($(id).position().left)
    }, 600);
}
```

Check it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/d3athR0n/S8Nqm/2/)

**UPDATE:**

Just add an else condition, check the update code above.

[Link](http://jsfiddle.net/d3athR0n/S8Nqm/3/)

Comment: you understand what I need but does not work properly, in the sense that if I click on the menu scrolling slideshow (About, work, etc.) does not work, do not move more pagin. Instead I would like to get to the different pages, either via the ClickHere both from the top menu. thanks