# Increase and Decrease te side of div on Chrome-Safari

Tags: jquery, html

i use this code for increase and decrease the size of a div :

```
$("#div1").hover(function() {
                var $this = $(this);
                $this.css({'z-index' : '10', 'boxShadow' : '1px 3px 6px #444', 'position': 'fixed' }).animate({
                    'height': "390",
                    'width' : "840",
                    'marginTop' : "-12",
                    'marginLeft' : "-12",


                });
            },function() {
                   var $this = $(this);
                   $this.css({'z-index' : '1', 'boxShadow' : '0px 0px 0px ', 'position': 'static' }).animate({
                    'height': "350",
                    'width' : "800",
                    'marginTop' : "0",
                    'marginLeft' : "0"
                });
            });



            $("#div2").hover(function() {
                var $this = $(this);
                 $this.css({'z-index' : '10', 'boxShadow' : '1px 3px 6px #444', 'position': 'fixed' }).animate({
                    'height': "270",
                    'width' : "290",
                    'marginTop' : "-12",
                    'marginLeft' : "-12",


                });
            },function() {
                   var $this = $(this);
                   $this.css({'z-index' : '1', 'boxShadow' : '0px 0px 0px ', 'position': 'static' }).animate({
                    'height': "250",
                    'width' : "250",
                    'marginTop' : "0",
                    'marginLeft' : "0"
                });
            });
```

Why on Chrome and Safari don't work properly?

In Firefox work correctly but in Chrome-Safari when increase the size of div the div moves and the div is moved to another location.

No console error.

EXAMPLE: http://jsfiddle.net/d3athR0n/S8Nqm/3/

Thanks.

EDIT: Other question for your help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17460335/slideshow-glitching-on-chrome-safari-with-jquery

Comment: Do I understand this right you asked the same question five times ([1](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17458917/1935077), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17229493/1935077), [3](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17459719/1935077), [4](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17460335/1935077) and this one is the 5th)?

Comment: and how many answers that have helped me have I got? instead of pointing out how many times I ask a question (no response) I'd be helpful and provided me help. thanks

Comment: If you read what I wrote Mike in question 1, you would know that it was he who suggested to divide the issues into several parts , and so I did , excluded the question number 1, the rest are issues with a different

Comment: Okay, I just asked, it looks similar, but few sentences are different in each questions :-) You can ask 10 more questions *(I'm not the one how closes questions anyway)* with no answers or edit your existing questions and explain what your problem is in more details (your code is working fine for me in Google Chrome on Linux). I'm sorry I can't help you with your issue -- but I just can't see what the issue is.

Comment: the questions are really a copy and paste from the number 1, however in the meantime I thank you for trying. The best thing I think it is post a video, and then I realize I add it to this question so do not open further and I hope someone give me an answer. Thank you.

Comment: @netkingZ It works perfectly fine for me in Chrome on Windows 7. Could you describe the problem some more?

Comment: @netkingZ [This is how the your jsFiddle behaves on my computer.](http://youtu.be/K6QJL8TuLfo) In Firefox it works exactly the same.

Comment: See this : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BkvN6hRswEs&feature=youtu.be